# TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined " when I hover over `heading` .
I think, this is because I used `useRef()` wrong. Any Idea how to fix it?

```js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react'; // 

function Main (
  const refs = useRef()

  const onMouseMove = () => {
    const width = refs.heading.clientWidth
    const height = refs.heading.clientHeight
    console.log(width,height);
  }

  return (
    <div className='home__main-text-wrapper' >
      <h1 className='heading'
      onMouseMove={onMouseMove}
      ref={refs}>
      Get your pet <br /> a perfect ID photo
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `current` property of the `ref`.

```
    const width = refs.current.clientWidth
    const height = refs.current.clientHeight
```

For more details, read the docs - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref